# List processes by cpu system time

Tags: process, cpu-usage, metric, prometheus-exporter

I have a [Node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) up and running on my server, on my [dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860-node-exporter-full/) I see that my CPU time is mostly (+40%) spent in `system` mode which is not normal.

How can I list processes sorting them by CPU system time?